# My Laravel relationship problems

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to do browser game like Tribal Wars in Laravel.
I want to get building level by using `$wioska->buildings->Tartak->level`, but something not working:

[image]

This is my Building model:

```
class Building extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'budynki';
    public function Tartak(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Tartak');
    }
}
```

Wioska (village) model:

```
class Wioska extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'user_id'];
    protected $table = 'wioski';

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function buildings(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Building');
    }
}
```

And this is my Tartak model:

```
class Tartak extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'budynki';

        public function level(){
            $u = Auth::user();
            $id = $u->wioska->id;
            return DB::table('budynki')->where('wioska_id', $id)->first();
        }
    }
```

Migration "budynki":

```
public function up()
{
    if(!Schema::hasTable('budynki')) {
        Schema::create('budynki', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('town_hall')->default(1);
            $table->integer('iron')->default(0);
            $table->integer('wood')->default(0);
            $table->integer('stone')->default(0);
            $table->integer('bread')->default(0);

            $table->integer('wioska_id');
            $table->foreign('wioska_id')->references('id')->on('wioski');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't host code offsite. We shouldn't have to leave Stack Overflow to understand it. Also, please avoid posting textual data like your error message as a screenshot. Text can be searched, copied, and offers good accessibility. Images don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It's always good to check for a null entity before trying to call its methods. Example, if `$wioska->buildings` is null or wioska has no buildings, or buildings have no Tartak, then the rest of the line will throw errors.

2) `level()` is a method and since its not an authentic Laravel relationship, you will need to use it as a method, example - `$wioska->buildings->Tartak->level()`

Comment: Now I've got SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'budynki.building_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `budynki` where `budynki`.`building_id` is null and `budynki`.`building_id` is not null limit 1) I think its something wrong with DB on level function

Comment: It will also be better to explicitly set the foreign key and local key for all your relationships. Example - `hasOne(Tartak.class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');` and the same with `belongTo`. This will make sure that the key column names are accurate. See the laravel docs for more information on relationships.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'budynki.foreign_key' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `budynki` where `budynki`.`foreign_key` is null and `budynki`.`foreign_key` is not null limit 1)

Comment: That was error when I replace Tartak.class and Building.class with 'App\Tartak' and 'App\Building'. When I use Tartak.class and Building .class laravel throws FatalErrorException
syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS)
in Building.php (line 10)

Answer (score 0):

`level` is not property as per your model, so you have to try as below

```
$wioska->buildings->Tartak->level()
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I've got 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'budynki.building_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `budynki` where `budynki`.`building_id` is null and `budynki`.`building_id` is not null limit 1)  error
I just want to get tartak level from budynki table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3ZRG.png .

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here: `$u = Auth::user(); $id = $u->wioska->id;` ?

Comment: Im trying to get user's village's id to find good record in budynki table ;)